# Is it possible to handle mouse event in window that is not the key? (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have two NSWindows, A and B. Everything is using "standard" set-up, no customization so far. If window A is in focus (i.e. it is the key window), then clicking on window B makes it the key window. However, the clicking event is used up* by this action; meaning that `-mouseUp:` of window B is not called.

Is it possible to somehow grab the event and have it be handled by window B?

A **use-case** would be for example that B contains an NSTableView, and we want to immediately select an item in it, without the window having to get in focus first (one click is better than two clicks!).
Or, more generally, there's some NSView in window B with custom reaction to mouse events.

* The clicking event is not always used up: If the mouse event is a double click, then the first click makes B the key, while the second happens when B is key already, and because both clicks were close enough to form one event,  `-mouseUp:` in window B triggers.

Comment: Yes, thank you! For anyone with a similar problem: Make sure the view you want to capture the mouse event is top one in the view hierarchy.